# Range bucket values and create grid using R

Tags: r

Trying to learn how more R... looking to find a clean and easy to follow way to take orders DF:

`customerID  Timestamp freq  lat
1          1 2017-01-01    2 31.0
2          2 2017-01-01    3 90.5
3          3 2017-01-01    1  NaN
4          4 2017-01-01    1  NaN
5          1 2017-02-01    2 31.0
6          2 2017-03-01    3 90.5
7          2 2017-07-01    3 90.5`

And create a grid, with counts, based on a range of buckets for lat and freq. Buckets:

- freq (1, 2-4, 5+)
- lat (0-30, 31-60, 61+)

e.g.

      `lat
freq   61+    31-60      0-30
5+      0       0          0
2-4     3       2          0
1       0       0          2`

Dput:

```
> dput(orders)
structure(list(customerID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L), Timestamp =             
structure(c(17167, 
17167, 17167, 17167, 17198, 17226, 17348), class = "Date"), freq = c(2L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), lat = c(31, 90.5, NaN, NaN, 31, 90.5, 
90.5)), .Names = c("customerID", "Timestamp", "freq", "lat"), row.names = 
c(NA, 7L), class = "data.frame")
```

**UPDATE**

Been working through this... I used `cut` to do the bucketing ... not sure if the best route though. Not sure how to do the grid though however.

e.g.

`orders$freq_range <- cut(orders$freq, breaks=c(0,1,4,100000), labels=c("1","2-4","5+"))`

Comment: I tried using the ```cut``` function, however, I can't seem to figure out how to do the final bin which is 5+ for freq and 61+ for lat. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean you can't figure out the last bin? if you've 5 and more in the freq column, 5+ is the bin. and `df$lat_range <- cut(df$lat, breaks=c(0,30,60,100000), labels=c("0-30","31-60","60+"))` will give you the lat bins. I don't see a problem.

Comment: Sorry, I posted an update for this part but forgot to comment back here. I got the bins working. Now I'm trying to make the grid part output work... I added the bins to the original orders DF

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `table` to get the cross table output:

```
df

customerID  Timestamp  freq   lat
1           2017-01-01  2    31.0
2           2017-01-01  3    90.5
3           2017-01-01  1      NA
4           2017-01-01  1      NA
1           2017-02-01  2    31.0
2           2017-03-01  3    90.5
2           2017-07-01  3    90.5
2           2017-07-01  5    90.5
3           2017-07-01  6   100.5

df$a<-cut(df$freq, breaks=c(0,1,4,100000), labels=c("1","2-4","5+"))

df$b <- cut(df$lat, breaks=c(0,30,60,100000), labels=c("0-30","31-60","60+"))

df

customerID  Timestamp freq   lat   a     b
 1          2017-01-01    2  31.0 2-4 31-60
 2          2017-01-01    3  90.5 2-4   60+
 3          2017-01-01    1    NA   1  <NA>
 4          2017-01-01    1    NA   1  <NA>
 1          2017-02-01    2  31.0 2-4 31-60
 2          2017-03-01    3  90.5 2-4   60+
 2          2017-07-01    3  90.5 2-4   60+
 2          2017-07-01    5  90.5  5+   60+
 3          2017-07-01    6 100.5  5+   60+

table(df$a, df$b)

       0-30 31-60 60+
  1      0     0   0
  2-4    0     2   3
  5+     0     0   2
```

Comment: Awesome! That's great. Is there a way to order the X and Y DESC by the bins?

Comment: Away from my machine. But sort (table (df$a, df$b)) should do.

Comment: sort didn't seem to work, output was turned out to be: [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 3